# Criar usuário no AD informando o grupo C# forms

Tags: c#

Boa noite pessoal!

Já tenho o código que criação de usuário no AD com LDAP, e agora estou querendo já criar esse usuário informando o grupo, ja pesquisei e não  encontrei a solução ainda, tenho o seguinte código:

```
 private static void createUser(string domainAD, 
                                   string nameAD, 
                                   string passwordAD, 
                                   string nameUser, 
                                   string Description, 
                                   string password, 
                                   string OU, 
                                   string DOM, 
                                   string DC)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(
                                     ContextType.Domain,
                                     domainAD,
                                     "OU="+OU+",DC="+DOM+",DC="+DC+"",
                                     nameAD,
                                     passwordAD);

        UserPrincipal usr = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        usr.Name = nameUser;
        usr.Description = Description;           
        usr.SetPassword(password);
        usr.Enabled = true;              
        usr.Save();
        usr.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
    }
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Não está claro.

Comment: @joy Peter esta é minha estrutura para criação de um usuário no AD.
Primeiro faco a conexão com o AD através do PrincipalContext e depois faco a criação do usuário com o UserPrincipal, o que estou querendo é fazer essa criação do usuário já informando o grupo, eu não achei a opção para inserir o usuário em um determinado grupo já na criação.